# File permission is 0666, but can not open even as root

Tags: c, linux, file-permissions, sudo

I am experimenting with `flock`:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    mode_t m = umask(0);
    int fd = open("/tmp/test.lock", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666);
    if(fd == -1){
        printf("open failed. errno: %d, %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    }
    umask(m);
    int res = flock(fd, LOCK_EX);
    if(res != 0){
        printf("flock failed. errno: %d, %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    }
}
```

If I run the executable with `sudo`, then normally, there is no error. However, if I run as a normal user, I get for the `sudo` process: `open failed. errno: 13, Permission denied`:

```
r@rvb-my:~/work$ gcc test.cpp
r@rvb-my:~/work$ ./a.out 
r@rvb-my:~/work$ ls -l /tmp/test.lock 
-rw-rw-rw- 1 r r 0 Jan 23 15:09 /tmp/test.lock
```

```
r@rvb-my:~/work$ sudo ./a.out 
open failed. errno: 13, Permission denied
flock failed. errno: 9, Bad file descriptor
r@rvb-my:~/work$ rm /tmp/test.lock
```

```
r@rvb-my:~/work$ sudo ./a.out 
r@rvb-my:~/work$ ls -l /tmp/test.lock 
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 Jan 23 15:09 /tmp/test.lock
r@rvb-my:~/work$ ./a.out 
r@rvb-my:~/work$ ls -l /tmp/test.lock 
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 Jan 23 15:09 /tmp/test.lock
```

Why is this happening and how can I create the lock file to be accessible for both processes in both cases?

Comment: OT:  Modifying the `umask` value of a process to ensure files are created with the exact mode specified is not thread-safe and can cause the original `umask` value to be lost.  If you need an exact mode, you need to use `[f]chmod()` after creation to do so in a thread-safe way.

Comment: When I see weird access control behavior like this on Linux, my first guess is usually that it has to do with mandatory access controls (SELinux).

Comment: If the call to `open()` failed your program shouldn't keep on trying to use a descriptor it returned like it succeeded. You print a message and just keep on going...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, Linux systems have the `/tmp` directory owned (and group-owned) by `root` and it has mode `1777/drwxrwxrwt`, which means that the "sticky" bit is set.

After:

```shell
r@rvb-my:~/work$ ./a.out 
r@rvb-my:~/work$ ls -l /tmp/test.lock 
-rw-rw-rw- 1 r r 0 Jan 23 15:09 /tmp/test.lock
r@rvb-my:~/work$ sudo ./a.out 
open failed. errno: 13, Permission denied
```

The `open()` call failed with `errno` set to `EACCES` because the current user is `root`, the file `/tmp/test.lock` already exists, the owner `r` of the file is neither the current user nor the owner of the containing directory `/tmp`, and the containing directory is both world- or group-writable and sticky. This error situation is documented in the Linux [**open(2)**](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) man page:

```
       EACCES Where O_CREAT is specified, the protected_fifos or
              protected_regular sysctl is enabled, the file already
              exists and is a FIFO or regular file, the owner of the
              file is neither the current user nor the owner of the
              containing directory, and the containing directory is both
              world- or group-writable and sticky.  For details, see the
              descriptions of /proc/sys/fs/protected_fifos and
              /proc/sys/fs/protected_regular in proc(5).
```

The file in question is a regular file so the `fs.protected_regular` sysctl setting controls the behavior. It is documented in the Linux [**proc(5)**](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) man page:

```
       /proc/sys/fs/protected_regular (since Linux 4.19)
              The value in this file is/can be set to one of the
              following:

              0   Writing to regular files is unrestricted.

              1   Don't allow O_CREAT open(2) on regular files that the
                  caller doesn't own in world-writable sticky
                  directories, unless the regular file is owned by the
                  owner of the directory.

              2   As for the value 1, but the restriction also applies
                  to group-writable sticky directories.

              The intent of the above protections is similar to
              protected_fifos, but allows an application to avoid writes
              to an attacker-controlled regular file, where the
              application expected to create one.
```

If necessary, the setting could be disabled at runtime using the `sysctl` command (see [**sysctl(8)**](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sysctl.8.html)):

```sh
sudo sysctl fs.protected_regular=0
```

The setting may be set during system boot by editing the `/etc/sysctl.conf` or `/etc/sysctl.d/*.conf` files (see [**sysctl.conf(5)**](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sysctl.conf.5.html)):

```sh
fs.protected_regular = 0
```

However, changing the setting would make the system more vulnerable to attack.